# how to group by bi-weekly in google big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I think google big query provide function like DATE_TRUNC, but there is no bi-week parameter can use. So I wonder if there any way we can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

one option is using `generate_date_array` function and passing the 2 weekly parameter.

You can then use this in your query as inner join to extract the bi-weekly slots. hope this answers your question.

```
SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(current_date(), current_date() + 90, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) as bi_weekly_dates
```